# Automatically set minutes to 00 after user selects hours in Bootstrap Vue Timepicker

Tags: html, vue.js, datetime, bootstrap-vue, bootstrap-datetimepicker

When user opens timepicker, hours and minutes should be empty. As soon as they select the hours, it should automatically set the minutes to 00. Thank you in advance.

```
<b-form-timepicker 
    v-model="meditation.start.time"                     
    locale="en" 
    :state="meditation.start.status"
    class="m-1"
    now-button
    required                    
    @input="meditationTimeChange(meditation.start)"
    label-close-button="Close"
    label-no-time-selected="Start Time"                 
>
</b-form-timepicker>

data() {        
    return {
        meditation: {
            disabled: true,
            message: 'Enter Date/Time',
            start:
            {
                time: '',
                status: false,
            }

meditationTimeChange(id){
    if(id.time === ''){
        id.status = false;
    } else {    
        id.status = true;
    }
    this.meditationValid();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using `@context` event which gets fired every time user clicks on one of the spinbuttons.

```html
<b-form-timepicker 
    v-model="meditation.start.time"                     
    locale="en" 
    :state="meditation.start.status"
    class="m-1"
    now-button
    required                    
    @context="onContext"
    label-close-button="Close"
    label-no-time-selected="Start Time"                 
>
</b-form-timepicker>
```

```js
onContext(ctx) {
  if(ctx.hours != null && ctx.minutes == null){
    this.meditation.start = `${ctx.hours}:00:00`
  }
}
```